# Too many logs in flutter app when touch on screen

Tags: flutter, android-10.0

i have created new project in flutter and not added any single line in that default project still 
it displays logs every time i touch on screen.

i think it is because of android 10 device.

anyone have any idea?

it gives below log every time i touch on screen

```
D/ColorViewRootUtil(29111): nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore false downY 1325 mScreenHeight 2340 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 3 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=425.0, y[0]=1325.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=11694678, downTime=11694678, deviceId=7, source=0x1002, displayId=0 } rotation 0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flutter sdk version v1.12.13+hotfix.8 you may face this issue because it is not stable.